# jquery ui slider bound to select step by 0.5

Tags: javascript

```js
    $(".needSlider").each(function() {
       var select = $(this);
        var slider = $("<div id='slider'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider({
          min: 1,
          max: 99,
          step:0.5,
          range: "min",
          value: select[0].selectedIndex + 1,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
          }
        });
        select.change(function() {
          slider.slider("value", this.selectedIndex + 1);
       });
    });
```

```html
<select id="minbeds1" class="needSlider">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
```

i have problem with step 0.5 when i select with select to 40.5 or 4.5 i have error in console Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[value=41.5]

Comment: here u go , sorry for that i am new here

Comment: You have to include jQuery and jQuery UI in your code snippet.

Comment: u can see it here i dont know how it didnt works here but here https://jsfiddle.net/5o5dtfwj/2/ it works. On my site step 0.5 didnt work

Comment: on my page i get error in console Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[value=41.5]